# why models.BooleanField returning bytes instead of Boolean value?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to assigning a boolean value to model.BooleanField

```
route = 'resend' # string

otp_object = models.Otp(
      blocked=(route == 'exposed')   # should be false
)
otp_object.save()
```

Here is where I am checking if the bool is true but it's returning **b'\x00'**

Even if I just write models.Otp( blocked=False) it still gives the same byte b'/x00'

which gives always True and prints 'work'

```
if otp_object.blocked:    # b'\x00'
     print('works')
```

Here first i am saving the data and then checking if the value is true then print  'works' but the value saved in the db is also false as shown below.
[image]

This is the model of the 'otp' table

```
class Otp(models.Model):
    blocked = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'otp'
```

I am using MySQL as database

I am unable to understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is `route`? A `string`? Something else?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what the issue is. Perhaps it might help to share the relevant model.

Comment: I don't understand problem. I don't understand your code - maybe because you did show minimal working example which we could run and test it.

Comment: I just edited the code can you please check

Comment: What python version are you using? And can you show the code between `otp_object.save()` and `if otp_object.blocked:` if there are any?

Comment: There isn't any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets

```
 otp_object = models.Otp( blocked=route == 'exposed')
```

Or.

```
 res = route =='exposed
 otp_object = models.Otp( blocked=res)
```

Edit: As it became clearer in the comments below, the table is unmanaged therefore, the table structure may not match the Model, and blocked is it set to a bit not a tinyint in MySQL so that is why the value is not parsed as Boolean by Django so the proposed solution is

```
if otp_object.blocked  == b'\x00':   # which means False
     print('works')
```

Comment: still same problem

Comment: Even if I just write models.Otp( blocked=False) it still gives the same byte b'/x00'

Comment: ooh, `managed = False`, can you share the table structure on DBMS (with field types) as this table wasn't created by migrations.

Comment: I didn't understand, I already shared the model

Comment: -- auto-generated definition
create table otp
(
    id                   varchar(255) not null primary key,
    blocked              bit          null,
);

This is what you mean,
and also there is bit datatype for blocked, is this what you mean causing the problem

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: MySQL is the DBMS

Comment: Alter the table to have the field as a `tiny int` and try again.

Comment: it's the prod database I can't do that 

Comment: the make your if condition compare with the bit, as this won't work without an alter.

Comment: ok thanks can you update the answer so that I can accept you answer